# Общение с USB-мышью на Windows - как? (обратная разработка)

Tags: windows, обратная-разработка, usb, мышь

Здравствуйте!

Ситуация вкратце такова: есть *USB*-мышь, имеющая дополнительную функциональность - переключение режимов чувствительности, в частности. К ней есть программа для *Windows* от изготовителя, позволяющая выполнять переключение программно - выбираешь в программе режим (*400dpi*, *1200dpi*, *2000dpi* и т.д.), нажимаешь *Apply* и мышь в ответ бодро мигает подсветкой  — мол, режим переключён.

Возникла необходимость реализовать такую же функцию самостоятельно. Я перехватил пакеты, уходящие мышке от родного софта при переключении режимов, выяснил что при этом софт отсылает мыши четыре пакета. Отправляемые *RAW*-данные у меня есть. Как мне воспроизвести подобное? Язык программирования — любой, желательно что-то скриптовое под Windows.

(ответьте, пожалуйста, подробно — я совсем не программист, и в некоторых случаях даже гугл не помогает)

Comment: как вы перехвотили пакеты? через локальные порты между приложениями или значении USB порта?

Comment: Если был порт был не USB а COM - можно было бы так как описано [тут](http://oliversmith.io/technology/2009/10/24/powershell-and-arduino-serial-communication/). И к тому же с использованием PowerShell

Comment: Возился с чем-то подобным(пульт от тюнера). Вполне возможно, драйвер мыши и управляющее приложение взаимодействуют при помощи стандартного механизма WindowsMessage API. Если так, то чтобы их отослать надо изучить структуру месаджа и скорее всего в rParam/lParam есть управляющие байты, которые меняются в зависимости от режима.

Comment: Пакеты перехватывали варешарком? Можете выложить результат захвата? А ещё все дескрипторы устройства, посмотреть которые можно в usbview. Вообще, скорее всего используется какое-то расширение hid и соответственно нужно просто понять что за пакеты и с чем. Потом гуглить по особенностям винды или попытаться использовать hidapi. Есть ещё тул anyhid, вроде позволяет всякие запросы формировать, стоит попробовать. Winusb тоже может помочь, если hid для данной настройки не используется, но нужно назначить драйвер устройству при помощи zadig или libwdi

Answer (score 1):

Вы планируете делать свое "железо" или использовать ту же самую мышь?

В первом случае - [winusb](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff540174(v=vs.85).aspx).

Во втором случае - надо перехватывать не USB-пакеты, а протокол общения программы с драйвером мыши (скорее всего, это вызовы DeviceIOControl)

Comment: Пытался недавно использовать winusb для перечисления USB-устройств. Не взлетело, выдавало малопонятную ошибку 0x07. Судя по всему, нужно устанавливать этот самый WinUSB. Так что я бы смотрел на пакеты и слал через IOCTL...

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов как вы отправите пакеты без драйвера? На винде это невозможно.

Comment: И в самом деле перепутал: думал что так получаю дескриптор, а у меня IOCTL_USB_GET_DESCRIPTOR_FROM_NODE_CONNECTION там, оказывается. Значит, придется с winusb разбираться...

Answer (score -1):

1. Перехватываем пакеты для всех режимов
2. Записываем их в нашу программу
3. Ищем мышь.
4. При необходимости отправляем их с нашей программы на *usb*-порт, к которому подключена мышь.
5. ...
6. PROFIT!

Comment: Не хватает разве что пункта 5. Profit!